# Update de resultado de outra tabela

Tags: sql, postgresql

Possuo o seguinte SQL:

```
SELECT id_grade
      ,MAX(data_lancamento)
  FROM faturamento_produtos
 WHERE data_lancamento < '01-01-2010'
 GROUP BY id_grade
```

Onde o mesmo faz a busca apenas do que foi lançado antes de 2010.

Possuo outra tabela que quero alterar um campo conforme o resultado deste `SELECT`.

**Resumindo:**
Quero colocar a coluna `quantidade_estoque = 0` da tabela `produto_estoque` para o que teve data de lançamento anterior a 2010.

Ambas as tabelas possuem o mesmo campo `id_grade`.

Comment: Já tentou o JOIN?

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza, vou dar uma olhada, mas sabe se daria certo no postgres?

Comment: No postgres, não sei. não tinha visto que era esse banco.

Answer (score 1):

Veja se é isso que entendi...

```
update pq
set quantidade_estoque = 0
from produto_estoque pq
join (
        SELECT id_grade,max(data_lancamento) 
        FROM faturamento_produtos 
        where data_lancamento < '01-01-2010' 
        group by id_grade
     )fp
on fp.id_grade = pq.id_grade
```

Comment: Não sei nas versões mais novas do postgres, se não me engano da 9.0 pra trás é só assim http://stackoverflow.com/a/7869611/1342547

Comment: @rray Ups, não tinha visto que era [postgres](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql), essa solução seria para sql server

Comment: :P é estranho usar a sintexe ansi 89 pra join.

Comment: Infelizmente não funciona no postgresql mesmo, ocorre o seguinte erro: relation pq does not exist.